# Serving fonts using webpack in Phoenix framework

Tags: webpack, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using Phoenix 1.4 rc with webpack(by default).
And I am having trouble with serving fonts in my app.
I added fonts in assets/fonts folder.then run it.
webpack complain about it like this..

```
./fonts/dashboard.ttf
    Module parse failed: Unexpected character '^@' (1:0)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type
```

So I googled about it and add this code in webpack.config.js

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
```

And run it. There is no complain from webpack but when I go to my app. it says

```
(Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError) no route found for GET /css/b06871f281fee6b241d60582ae9369b9.ttf
```

And Phoenix doesn't generate 'fonts' folder in priv/static folder.

And I can find fonts file in priv/static/js folder

I think in webpack.config.js file, output path is "/priv/static/js".. So How can I properly serve fonts file? and what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try adding them to your static folder Tae. e.g. assets/static/fonts

Comment: did you put fonts in assets/static/css folder?

Comment: I tried to add font folder to both of them. but I got same erros

Answer (score 1):

Rather than putting it with the js folder you can provide an `outputPath` to `file-loader`:

```
{
  test: /\.(svg|woff2?)$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options : {
      name: '[name].[ext]',
      outputPath: '../fonts',
    }
  }],
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got it work (hopefully), maybe not the best practice:

Since font files go into "/priv/static/js", I added "publicPath" like this, so they can be found from .css files:

```
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js'),
    publicPath: "../js/"  // <-------------------------- added this
  },
```

Anyone has a better solution, please let me know.  Thanks a lot.